# How can I plot a function with parameters x,y but only in the `x<y` region

Tags: plotting

I want to use DensityPlot to plot the function, let's say `f[x,y]=xy`, but only in the `x<y` region with `0<x<3, 1<y<4`. How can I do this? What about other regions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

1. First, [define your function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html):

   ```
   ClearAll[f]
   f[x_, y_] := x y
   ```
2. Then set up a density plot using [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) and specifying appropriate ranges for the $x$ and $y$ variables; then provide an appropriate [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option to specify that the plot should only be drawn wherever $x<y$:

   ```
   DensityPlot[
     f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 4}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < y]
   ]
   ```

[image: density plot over desired region x<y]

---

3. For more complex regions, the approach is similar, except that you should have a way of generating a function that reports on whether an $(x,y)$ point is within your desired plotting region or not. Here is an example with a triangular region:

   ```
   rmf = RegionMember@Triangle[{{1.5, 1}, {2.5, 3}, {0.5, 3}}]
   DensityPlot[
     f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1, 4},
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, rmf[{x, y}]],
     PlotPoints -> 30
   ]
   ```

[image: triangular region plot]

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to define your function only for $x<y$ as follows

```
f[x_,y_]:=x y/;x<y
DensityPlot[f[x,y],{x,0,3},{y,1,4}]
```

this give you the same graphics.
[image]